# Unable to assign aliases across unions in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, alias

I am trying to create a mailing list from a table in my database, then search a column in that table which contains information on siblings, extract that sibling information, search for those siblings in the table, and then join those siblings to the original mailing list.

In the following code I try to assign the alias t1 to a select query.

```
SELECT * FROM CountyData AS t1
WHERE dt_dec BETWEEN #05-6-2018# AND #06-06-2018# 
AND RippleImport IS NULL 
AND (Date()-[dob])/365.25 <13.875 

UNION SELECT CountyData.*
FROM CountyData INNER JOIN 

(SELECT TRIM(String_Split([Siblings], 0, ";")) FROM t1 WHERE Siblings IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT TRIM(String_Split([Siblings], 1, ";")) FROM t1 WHERE Siblings IS NOT NULL 
UNION
SELECT TRIM(String_Split([Siblings], 2, ";")) FROM t1 WHERE Siblings IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT TRIM(String_Split([Siblings], 3, ";")) FROM t1 WHERE Siblings IS NOT NULL) t2

ON CountyData.[fname]&" "&[lname] = t2.[Expr1000] WHERE RippleImport IS NULL;
```

When I try to call that alias on the other side of the first union I receive the following error message.

```
'Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 't1'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.'
```

How do I assign a table alias which will be recognized throughout the entire query?

Comment: Probably can't. Inner query doesn't know the outer query. An outer query can see an inner query. Edit question to show example raw data and desired output.

Comment: You don't assign the alias `t1` to a select query, but to the table `CountyData`. This alias is visible until the 1st UNION statement.

Comment: Ok, so aliases aren't recognized globally, so to speak? Is there a join operation which appends records the way a union does? Or would joins have the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should correct the use of aliases in your code:

```
select t1.* from countydata t1
where t1.dt_dec between #05-6-2018# and #06-06-2018# 
and t1.rippleimport is null 
and (date()-t1.dob)/365.25 <13.875 
union
select t1.* from countydata t1 inner join 
(
    select trim(string_split(t1.siblings, 0, ";")) as sib from countydata t1 where t1.siblings is not null
    union
    select trim(string_split(t1.siblings, 1, ";")) as sib from countydata t1 where t1.siblings is not null 
    union
    select trim(string_split(t1.siblings, 2, ";")) as sib from countydata t1 where t1.siblings is not null
    union 
    select trim(string_split(t1.siblings, 3, ";")) as sib from countydata t1 where t1.siblings is not null
) t2 on t1.fname & " " & t1.lname = t2.sib 
where t1.rippleimport is null;
```

However, it may be more efficient to use calculated join criteria, e.g.:

```
select t1.* from countydata t1
where t1.dt_dec between #05-6-2018# and #06-06-2018# 
and t1.rippleimport is null 
and (date()-t1.dob)/365.25 <13.875 
union
select t1.* 
from countydata t1 inner join 
(
    select t.siblings as s from countydata t where t.siblings is not null
) 
t2 on 
(
    t1.fname & " " & t1.lname = trim(string_split(t2.s, 0, ";")) or
    t1.fname & " " & t1.lname = trim(string_split(t2.s, 1, ";")) or
    t1.fname & " " & t1.lname = trim(string_split(t2.s, 2, ";")) or
    t1.fname & " " & t1.lname = trim(string_split(t2.s, 3, ";"))
)
where t1.rippleimport is null;
```

The above is entirely untested.

Comment: Thanks, the first block you have given seems to have helped me with my problem. I am now able to use the alias in second half of the union within the those four lines of trim code. I can just assign my criteria here as well and it works as I want it. The second query you gave locked up my ms access.